# Retrive array of object from json array of object though http request typescript angular 5

Tags: json, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I want to retrieve array of object from another JSON array of object, which I am getting through HTTP request in angular 5 and want to display the values in console.Here I can successfully call the HTTP request and able to subscribe the service.

When parsing through *ngFor in template its working fine, but when I am directly accessing in typescript file, its showing undefined value in console.

My JSON like this.

```
{"data":[
   {
   userId: 1,
   id: 1,
   title: 'Loreum ispum',
   body: 'dummy text' 
   },
   {
   userId: 1,
   id: 1,
   title: 'Loreum ispum',
   body: 'dummy text' 
   },
   {
   userId: 1,
   id: 1,
   title: 'Loreum ispum',
   body: 'dummy text' 
   }]
}
```

I can access it though ngFor in html file, its giving the value, but when I am accessing in typescript like console.log(this.obj[data]); its showing undefined.

I need to create a new array which having only id and title field in angular 5
Kindly help. My Service page

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from'@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
private URL: string = 'some URL';
constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}
getData(): Observable<any>  {
return this.http.get(this.URL+ '/getdata', {responseType: 'json'});
}
}
```

My component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from '../services/config.service';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { FlatTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class childComponent implements OnInit {
allData: any = [];
  getALLData() {
    this.config.getData().subscribe(
      data => { this.allData= data['data']},
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('done loading data')
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getALLData();
    console.log(this.allData);   //here its showing undefined in console
  }
}
```

Kindly help on this

Comment: try `console.log(this.obj.data)`

Comment: Can you show your component / service code?

Comment: Json cant have ‘=‘ inside. Do you mean ‘:’

Comment: this is my service

Comment: export class ConfigService {

 constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}
  getFoods(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {responseType: 'json'});
}
}

Comment: this is my component

Comment: getData() {
    this.config.getFoods().subscribe(
    data => { this.data = data},
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log(this.data)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getData();
 }

Comment: yes inside its having :   and i tried like this console.log(this.obj.data) its not working showing undefined

Comment: You should update your question with the code, not post them as comments.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code, kindly look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP service returns a *response* object which contains the data.

```
const request = this.http.get('...');

// The subscribe triggers the HTTP request, and you can call 
// subscribe again on the same variable to trigger another HTTP request
request.subscribe((resp)=>{ 
    // this will show the response object.
    console.log(resp);
});
```

You should call either `take` or `first` to ensure that the HTTP request is completed.

```
request.first().subscribe((resp)=>{ 
        // there are no memory leaks now
});
```

You should handle errors.

```
request
   .first()
   .catch((err,o)=>console.error(err))
   .subscribe((resp)=>{
       // called if only successful
   });
```

When the HTTP request is a success you can map the response to the actual data from the server.

```
request
   .first()
   .catch((err,o)=>console.error(err))
   .map((resp)=>resp.data)
   .subscribe((data)=>{
       // this will be the JSON from the server
       console.log(data);
   });
```

This is how I would write the HTTP service function.

```
 getFoods() {
     return this.http
                .get('....')
                .first()
                .catch((err,o)=>console.error('There was an error'))
                .map((resp)=>resp.data);
 }
```

Later in your component. You need to log the response data only after the observable has finished.

```
 this.data = null;
 console.log('data is null', this.data);
 this.server.getFoods().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.data = data;
      console.log('data is now set', this.data);
 });
 console.log('data is still null', this.data);
```

I think this answers your question as the data is lazy loaded after the HTTP request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

This is answer was helpful for retrieving json array data from api to angular.